# css style missed

Tags: css, vue.js

css style "background-position: center; " missed, why?because background will override background-position

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="div1" :style="'background-position: center; height:200px;width:300px;background: url('+imgURL +')'"></div>
</body>
<script>
  var vm = new Vue({
    el: "#div1",
    data: {
      imgURL: 'https://www.baidu.com/img/bd_logo1.png'
    }
  });
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: because background will override  background-position

Answer (score 1):

In your CSS you are replacing the `background-position` with `background` later on in the rules. If you change `background` to `background-image` it will work.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="div1" :style="'background-position: center; height:200px;width:300px;background-image: url('+imgURL +')'"></div>
</body>
<script>
  var vm = new Vue({
    el: "#div1",
    data: {
      imgURL: 'https://www.baidu.com/img/bd_logo1.png'
    }
  });
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: I was referring to the CSS contained in the `style` attribute of the `div` tag. If you compare my version to yours you'll see the change both in the code and in the resulting behavior.